# ¿Cómo crear una variable cuyo nombre sea el valor ingresado en un input?

Tags: javascript

Intenté buscar en `Google` pero me aparecen cosas que no me sirven.
¿Cómo puedo crear una variable que su nombre sea según el valor de un `input`?

O sea:

```
var inputText = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

y ahora crear una variable con nombre de lo que se ha ingresado en el `input`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Espero no interpretar mal tu consulta dejo este ejemplo y espero que te sirva.

Este es un ejemplo de como implementar con un for y usar window para armar tu variable

```
for(var i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    window['v'+i] = "hola " + i;
}

alert(v0); // hola 0
alert(v1); // hola 1
alert(v2); // hola 2
alert(v3); // hola 3
```

Otro ejemplo más simple que podrá ayudarte a usarlo para el caso que tu necesitas :

```
var myVariable = 'mi';
window[myVariable] = 'prueba';

alert(mi); // se muestra : prueba
```

Entonces, el valor "mi" de myVariable se convierte en una variable llamada mi.

Por que todas las variables en el scope global son propiedades del objeto Window

De nuevo espero que sea de ayuda!

Comment: Gracias¡! Supongo que el primer ejemplo era alert(p1)

Comment: Sip, corregí el ejemplo. Espero que te sirva!